# Add rich card to QnA Maker with LuisDialog

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

Is there a way to add an adaptive card to the answer of a question in a qna maker?

My bot app uses LuisIntent as well. i have used this link: https://blog.botframework.com/2017/08/25/qna-maker-rich-card-attachments-net/

From what i understand it uses a qnadialog in order to get the relevant question and therefore return the relevant answer and display the desired adaptive card, however this method does not uses LUIS. My app uses luisintent to identify the relevant question.

Thank you in advance

Comment: That blog post just gives a few examples of how cards could be implemented in a QnA bot. You are meant to adjust the code to suit your own purposes. Please update your question to include relevant formatted code that indicates how you're using LUIS and QnAMaker and how you've already tried to incorporate rich cards. Please also show how you're formatting your QnA answers.

Comment: Are you still working on this?